# Put computed value inside progress bar Knockout js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a computed value here,

```
self.total_remain_percent = ko.computed(function() {
            var x = 0;
            var y = 0;
            var z = 0;
            var a = 0;
            $.each(self.paymentPlan(), function (index, item) {
                x += parseFloat(item.total_paid());
            });
            $.each(self.paymentPlan(), function (index, item) {
                y += parseFloat(item.total_payment());
            });
            a = y-x ;
            z = (a/y) * 100;
            return z.toFixed(0);
        });
```

Which I need to show it in a progress bar , I used knockout observable to bind with the progress bar, but I cannot display it, here is how the progress bar is done.

```
self.progress = ko.observable(10);
```

`<div data-bind="progress: progress"></div>`
For now the value in progress bar shows and also the computed value shows 100,

```
<span data-bind="text : $data.total_remain_percent"></span>
```

But I need to show this total remain percent, on the progress bar,

I tried it in this way , but did not work

```
self.progress = ko.observable(self.total_remain_percent);
```

And
  `self.progress = ko.observable(self.total_remain_percent());`
Need help on putting the value there.

Comment: Where is the definition for `ko.bindingHandlers.progress`?

Comment: I took off the progress bar from here, the binding handler might be in the js file in here https://faulknercs.github.io/Knockstrap/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a general note, don't call your variables `x`, `y`, `z` and `a`.

```
self.total_remain_percent = ko.computed(function() {
    var totalPaid = 0;
    var totalPayment = 0;
    var remain = 0;
    var remainPercent = 0;
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.paymentPlan(), function (item) {
        // Why aren't item.total_paid and item.total_payment numbers?
        // There should not be any calls to parseFloat() here.
        totalPaid += parseFloat(item.total_paid());
        totalPayment += parseFloat(item.total_payment());
    });
    remain = totalPayment - totalPaid;
    remainPercent = remain / totalPayment * 100;
    // this is all about numbers, so let's return a number (toFixed returns strings)
    return Math.round(remainPercent);
});
```

and

```
<div data-bind="progress: total_remain_percent"></div>
```

should work fine, assuming that the `progress` binding turns the `<div>` into a progress bar representation.

Comment: I don't know, but you can easily find out by changing the last line line in the function and testing it afterwards.